# TortoiseSVN command line diff

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn, diff

The command I'm using is:

```
TortoiseProc /command:diff /path:myfile.txt
```

It will open up the diff TortoiseSVN window, but it will only compare the working copy with the HEAD copy.  What I want is to compare the working copy with the latest version in the Repo that is different. Basically, the same as running the right-click->TortoiseSVN-> "Diff" if the HEAD is different from the working copy.  Otherwise running the right-click->TortoiseSVN -> "Diff with Previous Version"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the registry DWORD value

```
HKCU\Software\TortoiseSVN\Debug
```

and set its value to 1.

After that, whenever you use any command, a dialog will pop up first showing you the exact command line parameters TortoiseProc.exe is started with.

Once you know the command you want to use, you can remove the registry entry again.

Comment: That gives a popup of the parameters, but they're the same as what I pass in.  Nice, but doesn't help with the question at hand.

Comment: How does it not help? You said you wanted to do the same as "right-click, etc.". So set the registry key and then execute that command.
If that's not what you want, you asked the question wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested, but this *should* work according to [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

```
TortoiseProc /command:diff /startrev:WORKING /endrev:HEAD /path:myfile.txt
```

Comment: when I try this, I get a popup that says 
URL 'file:///myfile.txt' non-existent in revision 0

Comment: /endrev:HEAD doesn't work. You need to use /endrev:-1 to get the HEAD.

Comment: Being a shell extension, TortoiseSVN expects complete file specs, including the full absolute directory information; it won't take the current working directory into account.

Comment: I couldn't get this working (I would either get file not existing errors, or invalid revision errors). Using the other answer, the command used by TortoiseSVN's right-click menu seems to be either `/command:prevdiff` or `/command:showcompare` depending on context.